# PL/SQL procedure - too many values

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm sure this is something simple, but I'm really new to PL/SQL and this has me stuck.

I've written a simple stored procedure to return a few values about a customer. Right off the bat, the `%rowtype`'s are not coming up as reserved keywords but the compiler isn't flagging those as errors.

It is, however, ignoring the entire SQL statement flagging the line `FROM demo_customers` as `too many values`. Even if I try reducing it to only select one column it still gives me the same error.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE GETCUSTOMER 
(
  arg_customerID demo_customers.customer_id%type,
  returnRec OUT demo_customers%rowtype
) 
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT  customer_id, cust_first_name, cust_last_name, cust_email
  INTO    returnRec
  FROM    demo_customers
  WHERE   customer_id = arg_customerID ;

END GETCUSTOMER;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to select into a %ROWTYPE record, you'll want to do a `SELECT *` rather than selecting individual columns

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE GETCUSTOMER 
(
  arg_customerID demo_customers.customer_id%type,
  returnRec OUT demo_customers%rowtype
) 
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT  *
  INTO    returnRec
  FROM    demo_customers
  WHERE   customer_id = arg_customerID ;

END GETCUSTOMER;
```

If you select 4 columns explicitly, Oracle expects you to have 4 variables to select those values into.