# Returning TABLE type from Procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, bulk-collect

I was testing this code to return a TABLE type from a procedure,  but I am getting an error which I believe should not happen as I am taking table type of the entire row of employees table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_pkg
IS

  TYPE my_rec IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE;

  PROCEDURE my_proc(p_out OUT my_rec);

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg
AS

  PROCEDURE my_proc(p_out OUT my_rec) AS BEGIN

      SELECT
        employee_id,
        first_name,
        last_name BULK COLLECT INTO p_out
      FROM employees;
    END;

END;
/
```

> 6/65           PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values 6/1
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Also what's the advantage and disadvantages of using TABLE type over REF CURSOR to return value from a procedure ?

Comment: Try `select *` instead of `select employee_id,first_name,last_name`

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure of Employees tables. As this error usually comes in case of mismatchin the no of columns in the select and the type.

Comment: It's the employees table which is in HR schema

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PL/SQL procedure - too many values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852641/pl-sql-procedure-too-many-values)